# UPDATE column values of a table based on no child rows in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an "items" table:

```
item_id |      expiration       | status 
------------------------------------------
   1    |  2014-04-02 12:00:00  |  NULL
   2    |  2014-04-01 17:00:00  |  NULL
   3    |  2014-03-31 17:30:00  |  NULL
   4    |  2014-04-14 19:00:00  |  NULL
```

and an "bids" table:

```
 bid_id  | item_id | withdrawn | amount
---------------------------------------
   1     |    1    |    NULL   |   10
   2     |    1    |    NULL   |   20
   3     |    1    |    NULL   |   30
   4     |    2    |     1     |   15
   5     |    4    |    NULL   |   10
```

The item_id column in the bids table is the child of item_id in the items table.

I need to figure out an UPDATE query that does one of two things:

1. Adds 7 days to expiration if the item is expired *(expiration < NOW())* and there are no bids for it in the bids table.
2. Or updates the item's status to sold if the item is expired and there are bids for it in the bids table.

So given the data in the two tables above and today's date of 4/4/14, the results of the update query I need would:

1. Update the status of item 1 to sold *(since it has expired and there are bids for it)*.
2. Add 7 days to the expiration of item 2 *(since it has expired and the only bid for it was withdrawn)*.
3. Add 7 days to the expiration of item 3 *(since it has expired and there are no bids for it)*.
4. Ignore item 4 *(since it has not yet expired)*.

Anyway, I'm having trouble trying to figure out the proper query. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking the time.

Best,
Josh

Comment: Share your attempt please...

Comment: I can't figure out where to start or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did:

1.Adds 7 days to expiration if the item is expired (expiration < NOW()) and there are no bids for it in the bids table.

```
update items set expiration = timestampadd(day, 7, expiration) where expiration < now()
and 0 = (select count(*) from bids where bids.item_id = items.item_id and isnull(withdrawn) );
```

2.Or updates the item's status to sold if the item is expired and there are bids for it in the bids table.

```
update items set status = "sold" where expiration < now()
and 0 < (select count(*) from bids where bids.item_id = items.item_id and isnull(withdrawn) );
```

Comment: Hey, that is working! What is the significance of the 0? Can you explain that?

Comment: the select in the where clause returns the count of matching rows in the bids table. so if there is no match in the fist statement (0 = ...) the expiration is extended and if there is a match (0 < ...) the status is sold.

Comment: Ok, I see that now. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Both parts together.

```
UPDATE items a 
    LEFT JOIN bids b
      ON a.item_id = b.item_id
        and b.withdrawn IS NULL
SET a.expiration = CASE WHEN b.bid_id IS NULL
                        THEN DATE_ADD(a.expiration,INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
                        ELSE a.expiration
                   END,
    a.status = CASE WHEN b.bid_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 'sold'
                    ELSE a.status
               END
WHERE expiration < NOW();
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e0a6/1)**

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE expiration < NOW()
SET a.expiration = CASE WHEN b.bid_id IS NULL
       ' at line 3

Comment: Almost. It just improperly changed item 2 status to sold because it failed to detect that the bid was withdrawn.

Comment: @JoshuaHutchison I your two points of explanation nothing about withdrawn bids. Now fixed.

Comment: You're right. I made a note about that but must have deleted by accident before I published question. Sorry for the confusion. Works good. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Part I:

```
UPDATE I
  SET expiration = DATE_ADD(I.expiration,INTERVAL 7 DAY)
FROM Items AS I
WHERE I.expiration < NOW() 
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Bids AS B WHERE B.item_id = I.item_id AND B.Withdrawn IS NULL)
```

Part II:

```
UPDATE I
  SET Status = 'Sold'
FROM Items AS I
WHERE I.expiration < NOW() 
  AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Bids AS B WHERE B.item_id = I.item_id AND B.withdraw IS NULL)
```

Comment: Before I test out, where do the queries account for ignoring bids that are withdrawn?

Comment: getting this on both: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM items AS I
WHERE I.expiration < NOW() 
  AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM bids AS' at line 3